# Can't get past an XML element

Tags: c#, xml

// I can't get past the Transaction element. I just get null element when reading in and trying to change the inner xml

```
    Assembly asmbly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(asmbly.GetManifestResourceStream        ("DaxWebServiceLib.sales.xml"));

    String nsu = xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
    XmlNamespaceManager xnsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
    xnsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", nsu);
    XmlElement xeID = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +"/ns:WorkstationID", xnsmgr);
    XmlElement xeID = XeID.InnerText = "0001"; 
                
    XmlElement xeDS = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +"/ns:WorkstationID", xnsmgr);
    xeDS.InnerText = storeNum + "0001";

    XmlElement xeseq = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +"/ns:SequenceNumber", xnsmgr);
    xeseq.InnerText = sequenceNo;  // figure out sequence number

    XmlElement xeCD = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML + "/ns:TransactionID", xnsmgr);
    xeCD.InnerText = _sessiontoken;
    XmlElement xeCD1 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +        "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:Sale/ns:POSIdentity/
       ns:POSItemID", xnsmgr);
    xeCD1.InnerText = UPC;
    XmlElement xeCD2 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +         "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:Sale/
        ns:ItemID", xnsmgr);
    eCD2.InnerText = UPC;
    XmlElement xeCD3 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +       "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:Sale/
       ns:Quantity", xnsmgr);
    xeCD3.InnerText = quanity;
    XmlElement xeCD4 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +        "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:ScanData", xnsmgr);
    xeCD4.InnerText = UPC;
    XmlElement xeCD5 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +           "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:SequenceNumber", xnsmgr);
    xeCD5.InnerText = sequenceNo;
    XmlElement xeCD6 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +        "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:BeginDateTime", xnsmgr);
    xeCD6.InnerText = SalesDTime;
    XmlElement xeCD7 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +           "/ns:RetailTransaction/ns:LineItem/ns:EndDateTime", xnsmgr);
    xeCD7.InnerText = SalesDTime;
    XmlElement xeCD8 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +"/ns:BusinessDayDate", xnsmgr);
    xeCD8.InnerText = SalesDTime;
    XmlElement xeCD9 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML +"/ns:BeginDateTime", xnsmgr);
    xeCD9.InnerText = SalesDTime;
    XmlElement xeCD10 = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode(shortcutXML+ 
       "/ns:BeginDateTime", xnsmgr);
    xeCD10.InnerText = SalesDTime;`
```

**XML**

```
<RetailTransactionLogDirectInsertRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                         MajorVersion="10"
                                         xmlns="http://retalix.com/R10/services">
    <POSLog>
        <Transaction xmlns:r10Ex="http://www.Retalix.com/Extensions"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" FixVersion="1"
                     xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
            <BusinessUnit>
                <UnitID>
                </UnitID>
            </BusinessUnit>
            <WorkstationID>
            </WorkstationID>
            <SequenceNumber>
            </SequenceNumber>
            <TransactionID>
            </TransactionID>
            <RetailTransaction>
                <LineItem>
                    <Sale>
                        <POSIdentity>
                            <POSItemID>00002200021558</POSItemID>
                        </POSIdentity>
                        <ItemID Type="X:EAN">00002200021558</ItemID>
                        <Quantity UnitOfMeasureCode="EA">1.000</Quantity>
                    </Sale>
                    <ScanData>00002200021558</ScanData>
                    <SequenceNumber>000000000000000002</SequenceNumber>
                    <BeginDateTime>2019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</BeginDateTime>
                    <EndDateTime>2019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</EndDateTime>
                </LineItem>
            </RetailTransaction>
            <BusinessDayDate>019-04-25</BusinessDayDate>
            <BeginDateTime>019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</BeginDateTime>
            <EndDateTime>019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</EndDateTime>
        </Transaction>
    </POSLog>
</RetailTransactionLogDirectInsertRequest>
```

If I change the transaction to IXRetail:transaction it finds that but won't find the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much better and easier to use *LINQ to XML* API.

It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<RetailTransactionLogDirectInsertRequest xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                                         xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                                         MajorVersion='10'
                                         xmlns='http://retalix.com/R10/services'>
            <POSLog>
                <Transaction xmlns:r10Ex='http://www.Retalix.com/Extensions'
                             xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                             MajorVersion='6' MinorVersion='0' FixVersion='1'
                             xmlns='http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/'>
                    <BusinessUnit>
                        <UnitID>
                        </UnitID>
                    </BusinessUnit>
                    <WorkstationID>
                    </WorkstationID>
                    <SequenceNumber>
                    </SequenceNumber>
                    <TransactionID>
                    </TransactionID>
                    <RetailTransaction>
                        <LineItem>
                            <Sale>
                                <POSIdentity>
                                    <POSItemID>00002200021558</POSItemID>
                                </POSIdentity>
                                <ItemID Type='X:EAN'>00002200021558</ItemID>
                                <Quantity UnitOfMeasureCode='EA'>1.000</Quantity>
                            </Sale>
                            <ScanData>00002200021558</ScanData>
                            <SequenceNumber>000000000000000002</SequenceNumber>
                            <BeginDateTime>2019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</BeginDateTime>
                            <EndDateTime>2019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</EndDateTime>
                        </LineItem>
                    </RetailTransaction>
                    <BusinessDayDate>019-04-25</BusinessDayDate>
                    <BeginDateTime>019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</BeginDateTime>
                    <EndDateTime>019-04-25T09:32:08.0000000</EndDateTime>
                </Transaction>
            </POSLog>
        </RetailTransactionLogDirectInsertRequest>");

    XNamespace ns1 = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/";

    xdoc.Descendants(ns2 + "WorkstationID").FirstOrDefault()?.SetValue("0001");
    xdoc.Descendants(ns2 + "SequenceNumber").FirstOrDefault()?.SetValue("18");
    xdoc.Descendants(ns2 + "TransactionID").FirstOrDefault()?.SetValue("sessionToken");
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}
```